# Excluding duplicate words from array and Randomise and limit array

Tags: php, arrays

Im creating a tag cloud from article subject titles.
I get each title, split into words and put them in an array, check word strlen > 3 and not in my excluded words array. This works great....

The bits im struggling with are:

- How to randomise the order and limit the output to say 20
- Excluding duplicates, and by duplicates I mean duplicate words but in the same catid.

For example below the word dog is repeated 5 times BUT in 3 different catid's. Therefore I would like to output the word dog 3 times once for each distinct catid.
    array:

```
'subject' => 'dog is running', 'id' => '1', 'catid' => '19'

'subject' => 'dog is walking', 'id' => '2', 'catid' => '18'

'subject' => 'dog is sitting', 'id' => '3', 'catid' => '18'

'subject' => 'dog is eating', 'id' => '4', 'catid' => '19'

'subject' => 'dog is barking', 'id' => '5', 'catid' => '20'
```

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
$excluded_word_array = array('a','blah','bleh');

// prepare the tag cloud array for display
$terms = array(); // create empty array

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hesk_kb_articles WHERE type = '0'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        $subject = $row['subject'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $catid = $row['catid'];
        $words = explode(" ", $subject);
        foreach ($words as $val){
                if (strlen($val) > 3) {
                        $stripped_val = strtolower(ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z]", "", $val));
                        if (!in_array($stripped_val, $excluded_word_array)) {
                        shuffle($stripped_val);
                        $terms[] = array('subject' => $stripped_val, 'id' => $id, 'catid' => $catid);
                        }
                }
        }
}

sort($terms);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Group BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)** for that:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hesk_kb_articles WHERE type = '0' GROUP BY subject, catid");
```

Also **mysql*** functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [**MySQLi**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used

**UPDATE1:**

Maybe this can help you :

```
$excluded_word_array = array('a','blah','bleh');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hesk_kb_articles WHERE type = '0'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $subject = $row['subject'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $catid = $row['catid'];
    $words = explode(" ", $subject);
    foreach ($words as $val){
        if (strlen($val) > 3) {
            $stripped_val = strtolower(preg_replace("[^A-Za-z]", "", $val));
            if (!in_array($stripped_val, $excluded_word_array)) {
                $terms[$catid][] = $stripped_val;
            }
        }
    }
}

$items = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term = array_unique($term);
    $items = array_merge($items, $term);
}
```

`$items` will contain all the words you want .

**UPDATE 2:**

If you want catid along with the words, changes the last for loop:

```
$i = 0;
$items = array();
foreach ($terms as $term_key => $term_value) {
    $term_value = array_unique($term_value);
    $items[$i]['catid'] = $term_key;
    $items[$i]['words'] = implode(',', $term_value);
    $i++;
}
```

Now $items will contain the catid and the words separated by comma.

**UPDATE 3:**

If you want each catid and words to be seperate then you can do :

```
$i = 0;
$items = array();
foreach ($terms as $term_key => $term_value) {
    $term_value = array_unique($term_value);
    foreach ($term_value as $term) {
         $items[$i]['catid'] = $term_key;
         $items[$i]['words'] = $term;
         $i++;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am splitting the subject into individual words and want the distinct words from that. is there no way of using array_unique and check the catid key if its the same

Comment: @Codded the above query with group by will give you distinct subject with distinct cat_id's. But how you want the output to be ?

Comment: @Codded Based on what you have provided in your question, this will work. Do you need any thing specific than this

Comment: I edited my question, each subject could be any amount of words... the output would be a list of distinct words based on catid. do you how I could do this in php without SQL.

Comment: @Codded you mean if the subjects are dog is running and dog is waiting, then you should get dog, is, running and waiting only right ?

Comment: yes, but if each word is in 2 or more catids then the word should appear 2 or more times

Comment: Thank you, this looks more like what I was after. although i need the array to be like this..... $terms_item = array('subject' => $stripped_val, 'id' => $id, 'catid' => $catid); as I echo the catid

Comment: @Codded I am not clear how do you want that.. you want each value in the array you mentioned above ? like array('subject' => 'running', 'id' => 1 'catid' => 19);   array('subject' => 'dog', 'id' => 1 'catid' => 19) like this ?

Comment: the update you have done above is great, it works :) but with each word ($items will contain all the words you want) I also need the $catid......... so, foreach ($items as $item) then echo $item['word'] & $item['catid']

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28498/discussion-between-codded-and-sabari)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hesk_kb_articles WHERE type = '0'");
```

With a SELECT * you can't DISTINCT or GROUP BY and you have to SELECT only fields you need unique.

A query like this will be helpful

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subject, catid FROM hesk_kb_articles WHERE type = '0'");
```

or

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT subject, catid FROM hesk_kb_articles WHERE type = '0' group by subject, catid");
```

The ID column is unique, so you can't use SQL to reduce the amount of records returned. If you need ID in PHP Code. You can get an id from SQL by subject-catid couple if you need it.

You should consider a UNIQUE constraint on your table for subject-catid couple to avoid that type of "duplicates", if a Tag subject exists in a category you shouldn't insert it again.

Comment: Can you please tell me Why we can't SELECT * with GROUP BY ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to select the distinct subject as the subject could any amount of words (and would theoretically all be distinct). I am splitting the subject into individual words and want the distinct words from that. is there no way of using array_unique and check the catid key if its the same

Comment: @Codded you can add a UNIQUE constraint in DB and use INSERT IGNORE. I am not sure but INSERT IGNORE will try to insert but if it fails you will not get any error.

Comment: @Sabari because if you group by a select * you have to group by every single column in the clause.